# Dynamically unpivot each column in list, powerquery

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to dynamically unpivot each column provided in a list.

```
(Table as table, ColumnNameList as list) as table =>
    List.Accumulate(
        List.Zip(ColumnNameList, {1..List.Count(ColumnNameList)}),
        Table,
        (state, column) => Table.Unpivot(state, column{0}, "Option" & column{1} & "Name", "Option" & column{1} & "Value")
    )
```

This code doesn't work though, how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you give an example before and after you expect when invoking this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a function to provide a unique column name, somewhat like how the power query visual editor will automatically create names if an existing column already has one.

Haven't been able to test how it works once you get past more than one with the same name though.

```
(Table as table, ColumnName as text) =>
    if Table.HasColumns(Table, ColumnName) then
        let
            NewName =
                if Text.At(ColumnName, 3) <> "." then
                    ColumnName & ".01"
                else
                    Text.Start(
                        ColumnName,
                        Text.Length(ColumnName) - 2
                    )
                    & Text.PadStart(
                        Text.From(
                            Number.FromText(Text.End(ColumnName, 2))
                            + 1
                        ),
                        2,
                        "0"
                    )
        in
            @FnTableNewColumnName(Table, NewName)
    else
        ColumnName
```

Then I changed the fuction I was working on, to call the naming function for both of the two extra parameters.

```
(Table as table, ColumnNameList as list) as table =>
    List.Accumulate(
        ColumnNameList,
        Table,
        (state, column) =>
            Table.Unpivot(
                state,
                { column },
                FnTableNewColumnName(state, "attribute"),
                FnTableNewColumnName(state, "value")
            )
    )
```